# UIViewRepresentable with an animation layer doesn't animate inside of a sheet

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I have a legacy `UIImageView` that animates using a `CABasicAnimation`. I wrapped that in a `UIViewRepresentable` in order to embed it inside a SwiftUI view. It works great for the main view, but in a view that is presented using a `.sheet` modifier, it doesn't animate. My entire code is below (compiled with Xcode 15.3).

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}

struct Microphone: UIViewRepresentable {
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIImageView, context: Context) {
  }
  
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
    let view = UIImageView(
      image:
        UIImage(
          systemName: "mic.circle.fill",
          withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 50,weight: .bold, scale: .large)
        )?
        .withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    )
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.tintColor = .green

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    animation.duration = 1.3
    animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.fromValue = 0.9
    animation.toValue = 1.1

    view.layer.add(animation, forKey: "scale")
    return view
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var showSheet = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Microphone() // <-- animates perfectly
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)

      Button("Show Sheet") { showSheet = true }
        .padding(.top)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
      VStack {
        Microphone() // <-- does not animate
          .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
      }
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

The reason I'm going with `UIViewRepresentable` is

1. That code has already been written, tested and accepted.
2. I was unable to make a native SwiftUI view that animated as smoothly, which is likely because my SwiftUI knowledge is still pretty rudimentary. I would gladly take a solution that gives me a smooth animation in pure SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the memory graph debugger, the `CABasicAnimation` created for the image view in the sheet is deallocated for some reason. From my experiments, I also found that the animation does get added if `layer.add(animation)` is called after some delay. I think this is either a SwiftUI bug or perhaps the view somehow isn't "ready" for an animation to be added.

Adding the animation in `layoutSubviews` works, at least:

```
class ImageViewSubclass: UIImageView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // optionally, check layer.animation(forKey: "scale") == nil first
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        animation.duration = 1.3
        animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = 0.9
        animation.toValue = 1.1
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "scale")
    }
}

// in makeUIView:

let view = ImageViewSubclass(...)
...
return view
```

There are probably other life cycle methods you can do this in.

---

A pure SwiftUI way to do such an animation would be:

```
struct Microphone: View {
    @State private var scale = 0.9
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "mic.circle.fill")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundStyle(.green)
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1.3).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                    scale = 1.1
                }
            }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent response, very helpful. I was probably close to 90% of the way there to a pure SwiftUI version; just couldn't figure out the proper way to configure the `withAnimation` block.